# Goal seek function in Python

Tags: python, optimization, nonlinear-optimization, quantitative-finance, scipy-optimize

I'm currently working on a project where I'm calculating an implied price for a financial instrument given 7 input numbers. Now I'm trying to reverse engineer the code to find the input parameter "volatility" given a fixed implied price. Is there any way of doing this in Python in a similar way to the GoalSeek function in Excel? I've stumbled over scipy.optimize on other threads, but I'm not sure this is a global/local optimization problem, as I'm actually trying to find a single specific value.

For example:

the function Process takes the following input parameters

```
Process(recbond=0.4, lamda=0.4, avgglobal=0.5, s=50, d=20, r=0.02, volatility=0.2)
```

and the function returns spread_implied = 4.56.

Now I'm trying to find the corresponding level of volatility that would get me to a spread_implied = 6 for example. I believe that the actual function has some non-linearities, but since I know that the volatility can only be between 0.01 and 0.9 in this case, I could define a corridor of values to check between.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: I would look into a scalar root finder, Scipy has a few.